# Show that if $M$ is Noetherian then there $ n_{0} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq n_{0}$, $0= \operatorname{Im}(f^{n}) \cap \ker(f^{n})$

Tags: ring-theory, modules

> Sean $M$ an $R$-module and $f: M \longrightarrow M$ an endomorphism of $M$. Show that if $M$ is Noetherian then there $ n_{0} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq n_{0}$, $0= \operatorname{Im}(f^{n}) \cap\ker(f^{n})$

Hint: $\ker(f) \leq M$,  we have the following chain of submodules of $M$
$$\ker(f) \leq\ker(f^{2}) \leq\ker(f^{3}) \leq \dots $$
as $M$ is Noetherian this chain stops in some $n_{0} \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $\ker(f^{n_{0}})= \ker(f^{n}) \ \forall n \geq n_{0} $, then
$\ker(f^{n_{0}})= \ker(f^{n})=\ker(f^{2n}) $ 
let $x \in \operatorname{Im}(f^{n}) \cap \ker(f^{n}) $ then $x \in \operatorname{Im}(f^{n}) \cap \ker(f^{2n}) $ then exist $m \in M$ such that $f^{n}(m)=x$, $f^{n}(x)$ and $f^{2n}(x)=0$ where $f^{n}(f^{n}(m))=f^{2n}(m)=0 $.

But I do not as conclude that $x$ equals $0$, or is there any other way to show this. Thanks

Comment: That's quite a hint! You got $f^{2n}(m) = 0$. But $\ker f^n = \ker f^{2n}$ so...?

Comment: Exercise: Use your result above to show that any surjective map from a Noetherian module to itself is surjective. @TTS Did you see my ping to you to the answer I gave on why any maximal ideal in $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ can be generated by $n$ - elements?

Comment: @BenjaLim Haven't had time to look at your new version, but I'm sure it's good.

Comment: @TTS Thanks to Jeff for providing the hint. Also, his isomorphism can be deduced from some standard isomorphisms involving tensor products.

Comment: Is *Sean* weird lingo the kids use now for phrases like *Consider an*?

Comment: @rschwieb I believe it's from Spanish: the verb "ser" means "to be" and this is the imperative form. Read it as "let". Probably it ought to be edited.

Comment: @TTS Good catch :) I was too tempted to read it as in "Sean Connery." I took Spanish ages ago, but definitely did not read any sentences that would begin "let be a...". That sounds very plausible.